# Spring State Machine UML

Tags: java, uml, state-machine, spring-statemachine

I am using papyrus to design a state machine and the using spring uml to import that model to java. I am trying to use time events dynamically. I am able to run it when it has a Literal integer and it is const. How can I set the Periode value of the time events from java after loading the uml design. I tried (on time events in the when section) with Opaque expression (as Expr) -> add language > bean. As done by actions and effects. how then should I proceed? Defining the bean in java? That would be the interface.

Here is the description, timeEvent1 is const. and timeEvent2 is set via expr. as opaque expression.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<uml:Model xmi:version="20131001" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20131001" xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/5.0.0/UML" xmi:id="_m6xMMCE7EeyjDr-lLLuZXg" name="TimeEvent">
  <packageImport xmi:type="uml:PackageImport" xmi:id="_m_NAQCE7EeyjDr-lLLuZXg">
    <importedPackage xmi:type="uml:Model" href="pathmap://UML_LIBRARIES/UMLPrimitiveTypes.library.uml#_0"/>
  </packageImport>
  <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:StateMachine" xmi:id="_m7zG8CE7EeyjDr-lLLuZXg" name="StateMachine1">
    <region xmi:type="uml:Region" xmi:id="_m8se0CE7EeyjDr-lLLuZXg" name="Region1">
      <transition xmi:type="uml:Transition" xmi:id="_w1Cc8CE7EeyjDr-lLLuZXg" source="_tVvrkCE7EeyjDr-lLLuZXg" target="_t8dtUCE7EeyjDr-lLLuZXg">
        <trigger xmi:type="uml:Trigger" xmi:id="_c13TICHHEeyjDr-lLLuZXg" event="_VcY0UCE8EeyjDr-lLLuZXg"/>
      </transition>
      <transition xmi:type="uml:Transition" xmi:id="_4nH5MCE7EeyjDr-lLLuZXg" source="_t8dtUCE7EeyjDr-lLLuZXg" target="_u54X0CE7EeyjDr-lLLuZXg">
        <trigger xmi:type="uml:Trigger" xmi:id="_evDpYCHHEeyjDr-lLLuZXg" event="_YXALUCE8EeyjDr-lLLuZXg"/>
      </transition>
      <transition xmi:type="uml:Transition" xmi:id="_hE6GcCHHEeyjDr-lLLuZXg" source="_u54X0CE7EeyjDr-lLLuZXg" target="_5y6W4CE7EeyjDr-lLLuZXg"/>
      <subvertex xmi:type="uml:Pseudostate" xmi:id="_tVvrkCE7EeyjDr-lLLuZXg" name="Initial1"/>
      <subvertex xmi:type="uml:State" xmi:id="_t8dtUCE7EeyjDr-lLLuZXg" name="State2">
        <doActivity xmi:type="uml:FunctionBehavior" xmi:id="_nCap4CHLEeyjDr-lLLuZXg" name="myAction">
          <language>bean</language>
          <body>myAction</body>
        </doActivity>
      </subvertex>
      <subvertex xmi:type="uml:State" xmi:id="_u54X0CE7EeyjDr-lLLuZXg" name="State3"/>
      <subvertex xmi:type="uml:FinalState" xmi:id="_5y6W4CE7EeyjDr-lLLuZXg" name="FinalState8"/>
    </region>
  </packagedElement>
  <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:TimeEvent" xmi:id="_VcY0UCE8EeyjDr-lLLuZXg" name="TimeEvent1" isRelative="true">
    <when xmi:type="uml:TimeExpression" xmi:id="_TkICACHHEeyjDr-lLLuZXg">
      <expr xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="_TkICASHHEeyjDr-lLLuZXg" value="1000"/>
    </when>
  </packagedElement>
  <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:TimeEvent" xmi:id="_YXALUCE8EeyjDr-lLLuZXg" name="TimeEvent2" visibility="protected" isRelative="true">
    <when xmi:type="uml:TimeExpression" xmi:id="_ZjjN0CHHEeyjDr-lLLuZXg">
      <expr xmi:type="uml:OpaqueExpression" xmi:id="_ZjjN0SHHEeyjDr-lLLuZXg" name="mT">
        <language>bean</language>
        <body>mT</body>
      </expr>
    </when>
  </packagedElement>
</uml:Model>
```

On java side, I am then loading the UML to infer the state machine:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableStateMachine
public static class Config1 extends StateMachineConfigurerAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineModelConfigurer<String, String> model) throws Exception {
        model
            .withModel()
                .factory(modelFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public StateMachineModelFactory<String, String> modelFactory() {
        return new UmlStateMachineModelFactory("classpath:mypath/statemachine.uml");
    }
}
```

So, in case of action and guards, not used here, (when set as bean in the papyrus enviornment) we can deal with them in java as follows:

```java
@Bean
public Action<String, String> myAction() {
        return new Action<String, String>() {

            @Override
            public void execute(StateContext<String, String> context) {
            }
        };
    }
```

How can I now use the bean "mT" from timeEvent2 to set the value of the time from java? to get it dynamically. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. I updated it with the UML

Comment: That's no UML model. That would have to be XMI (from OMG).

Comment: Can't you inject the bean as a component in your action and call it from the execute method?